# Android to Google calendar sync problems

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, sync, google-calendar

The option to sync calendars is missing from the list for my 2 Google accounts, following some issues with syncing after which I deleted calendar data and calendar storage data.

I have tried reloading the accounts and all the other options come back - except the Calendar sync!!

Please help..

Comment: have you tried adding a 3rd google account; preferably using mobile data, not wifi? see if that brings back calendar sync.

Comment: Creating a new account hasn't helped. Also if I go into the standard Android calendar (I use aCalendar usually) and try to add an account, there are no Gmail (and I now have 3) accounts listed...

Comment: sonofabitch - it worked! How I don;t know, but something has changed and restored the sync. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a new Google account, preferably via mobile data instead of Wi-Fi. It should restore the calendar sync option.

Comment: sonofabitch - it worked! How I don;t know, but something has changed and restored the sync. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are on a rooted device.

Use your preferred file explorer to browse to : **/system/app**

There should be two apk files. One the calendar app (*calendar.apk*) and the other *calendarprovider.apk*. The second apk provides proper synchronization between the google account and the actual calendar application which is probably missing or not working.

You should be able to find a replacement apk for your specific device and rom on XDA.

Comment: No the device is not rooted. Thanks for offering advice though - lukily another answer solved the problem!